# How to compute row-by-row/column-by-column multiplication?

Tags: java, image-processing, matrix, fft

I'm trying to understand how to implement the Fast Fourier Transform using the separability property.

Image from the book: Gonzalez, R. C., and R. E. Woods. "Digital Image Processing, 4th Global Edition."
[image]

According to this, as I understand, we must compute the matrix of complex sinewave values like this:

```
    Complex[] F = new Complex[i.width*i.height];
    for (int x=0;x<i.img.length;x++){
        F[x] = new Complex();
        double theta = -2 * Math.PI * (x/(double)i.img.length);
        F[x] = new Complex(Math.cos(theta), Math.sin(theta));
    }
```

So, our matrix is a 1D array with the size of our image.
And then we have to take an image and multiply it with row-by-row array F, and then take the processed image and multiply it with column-by-column array F.

What i can't understand is how to properly perform this row-by-row and column-by-column  multiplication.

Let's say we take F and separate its columns by chunks. I did it like this:

```
    int chunk = image.width;
    for(int f=0;f<F.length;f+=chunk){
        row = Arrays.copyOfRange(F, f, Math.min(F.length,f+chunk));
        for(int k=0; k < row.length; k++){
            row[k] = row[k].mul(image[k]);
            clone[k] = (byte) row[k].r;
        }
    }
```

But this is wrong, the row gets empty.

Should we actually cut the 1D F array like this in order to multiply it with pixel values? Or there's another way to compute the row-by-row and column-by-column multiplication? How it can be implemented in Java?